# Python module not found in virtualenv

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, pip, virtualenv

I've tried to install a python module:

```
virtualenv .
source bin/activate
pip install utmp
```

It seems to be installed:

```
(wtmp)chris@chris-nb:~/computer/wtmp$ find -iname utmp
./bin/utmp
./lib/python2.7/site-packages/utmp
```

But Python says it wasn't found:

```
(wtmp)chris@chris-nb:~/computer/wtmp$ ./wtmp.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./wtmp.py", line 3, in <module>
    import utmp
ImportError: No module named utmp
```

Is this a module issue? Did I do something wrong?

If it matters, the OS is Ubuntu.

Here's the re-install log:

```
(wtmp)chris@chris-nb:~/computer/wtmp$ pip install --upgrade --no-deps --force-reinstall utmp
Downloading/unpacking utmp
  Downloading utmp-0.4.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/home/chris/computer/wtmp/build/utmp/setup.py) egg_info for package utmp
    zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
    flake8.reporter: module references __file__
    flake8.tests._test_warnings: module references __file__
    flake8.tests.test_integration: module references __file__

    Installed /home/chris/computer/wtmp/build/utmp/flake8-2.4.1-py2.7.egg
    Searching for six
    Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/six/
    Best match: six 1.9.0
    Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/six/six-1.9.0.tar.gz#md5=476881ef4012262dfc8adc645ee786c4
    Processing six-1.9.0.tar.gz
    Writing /tmp/easy_install-oJJB7w/six-1.9.0/setup.cfg
    Running six-1.9.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-oJJB7w/six-1.9.0/egg-dist-tmp-1116oK
    no previously-included directories found matching 'documentation/_build'
    zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
    six: module references __path__

    Installed /home/chris/computer/wtmp/build/utmp/six-1.9.0-py2.7.egg
    Searching for mccabe>=0.2.1,<0.4
    Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/mccabe/
    Best match: mccabe 0.3.1
    Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/m/mccabe/mccabe-0.3.1.tar.gz#md5=9a1570c470ff5db678cc0c03d5c0c237
    Processing mccabe-0.3.1.tar.gz
    Writing /tmp/easy_install-uFdTms/mccabe-0.3.1/setup.cfg
    Running mccabe-0.3.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-uFdTms/mccabe-0.3.1/egg-dist-tmp-Q139di

    Installed /home/chris/computer/wtmp/build/utmp/mccabe-0.3.1-py2.7.egg
    Searching for pep8>=1.5.7,!=1.6.0,!=1.6.1,!=1.6.2
    Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pep8/
    Best match: pep8 1.5.7
    Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pep8/pep8-1.5.7.tar.gz#md5=f6adbdd69365ecca20513c709f9b7c93
    Processing pep8-1.5.7.tar.gz
    Writing /tmp/easy_install-BdNCrK/pep8-1.5.7/setup.cfg
    Running pep8-1.5.7/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-BdNCrK/pep8-1.5.7/egg-dist-tmp-rrUWb1
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'docs'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'docs'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'testsuite'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'testsuite'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'

    Installed /home/chris/computer/wtmp/build/utmp/pep8-1.5.7-py2.7.egg
    Searching for pyflakes>=0.8.1,<0.9
    Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyflakes/
    Best match: pyflakes 0.8.1
    Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pyflakes/pyflakes-0.8.1.tar.gz#md5=905fe91ad14b912807e8fdc2ac2e2c23
    Processing pyflakes-0.8.1.tar.gz
    Writing /tmp/easy_install-R5ltqy/pyflakes-0.8.1/setup.cfg
    Running pyflakes-0.8.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir     /tmp/easy_install-R5ltqy/pyflakes-0.8.1/egg-dist-tmp-a8CCFW
    zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
    pyflakes.checker: module references __file__
    pyflakes.checker: module references __path__
    pyflakes.test.test_api: module references __file__
    pyflakes.test.test_undefined_names: module references __file__
    pyflakes.test.test_undefined_names: module references __path__

    Installed /home/chris/computer/wtmp/build/utmp/pyflakes-0.8.1-py2.7.egg

    warning: no files found matching '*.rst' under directory 'docs'
    warning: no files found matching '*.py' under directory 'docs'
Installing collected packages: utmp
  Found existing installation: utmp 0.4
    Uninstalling utmp:
      Successfully uninstalled utmp
  Running setup.py install for utmp

    warning: no files found matching '*.rst' under directory 'docs'
    warning: no files found matching '*.py' under directory 'docs'
    Installing utmp script to /home/chris/computer/wtmp/bin
Successfully installed utmp
Cleaning up...
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can check whether it is installed in your virualenv by calling `pip list` or `pip show utmp`.

If not, try to reinstall it:

`pip install --upgrade --no-deps --force-reinstall utmp`

and extend your question with the error log.

Also verify the [shebang line](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/) as it might point not to your virtualenv.

Comment: It seems to be installed: (wtmp)chris@chris-nb:~/computer/wtmp$ pip list
argparse (1.2.1)
enum (0.4.4)
pip (1.5.4)
setuptools (2.2)
utmp (0.4)
wsgiref (0.1.2)

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall it: `pip install --upgrade --no-deps --force-reinstall utmp`?

Comment: I've added the re-install log above.

Comment: Can you try to launch python interpreter and just type `import utmp`. If this works, problem lies in the `wtmp.py` script. Check the [shebang line](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/) as it might point not to your venv.

Comment: Thank you! I used the wrong Shebang line! It's some time ago since I've used python and virtualenv the last time.

Comment: What could be the problem if I didn't set a shebang comment and all the other Workarounds also don't result in a solution?

Answer (score 21):

Just bumped into the same issue. I found out what is wrong by using `which python`. It showed me that I actually have an alias in place which points to a different python executable than the one in current `virtualenv`. Apparently aliases are more important than paths set via `source`.

Comment: Yes,aliases take precedence. Why is that related to the question?

Comment: It is related because this can be one of possible causes of why a Python module can not be found in virtualenv. If someone would have posted it here earlier, I would solve my problem faster, thus I thought I will add my solution as a hint here.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it happened to be the shebang line I had set to make my file self executing: '#!/usr/bin/python3/'

Once I switched over to using 'venv' module, I found it better to launch my app invoking 'python3 ./app.py' and removing the shebang line, this way to allow the virtual environment variables to call the correct Python binary.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).