# ModuleNotFoundError but pkg_resources found it

Tags: python, python-packaging

I am using on a Linux machine a venv with python 3.7.9 and installed one of my packages with pip. The install script should be fine because had no problem under windows with anaconda.

I installed the package in dev mode as also in normal mode.

If I try to import my package with:

```py
import my_package
```

I got the well known `ModuleNotFoundError`. So I checked the `sys.path` if the site-packages folder where my package is installed is included.

✅

Okay, So I checked which packages are available with `pkg_resources`:

```py
import pkg_resources
installed_packages = {d.project_name: d.version for d in pkg_resources.working_set}
print(installed_packages)
```

The result:

```sh
{'torchvision': '0.7.0', 'torch': '1.6.0', 'tensorboardX': '2.1', 'six': '1.15.0', 
'setuptools': '47.1.0', 'protobuf': '3.13.0', 'pip': '20.2.3', 'Pillow': '7.2.0', 
'numpy': '1.19.2', 'future': '0.18.2', 'my_package': '1.0', 'absl-py': '0.10.0'}
```

✅

As you can see my package is listed after future.

I have no clue why python struggles with importing my_package.
Anyone a Idea what am I doing wrong?

I already tested those solutions with no result:

[what shebang to use for python scripts run under a pyenv virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44076804/what-shebang-to-use-for-python-scripts-run-under-a-pyenv-virtualenv)

[Python module not found in virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32004958/python-module-not-found-in-virtualenv)

[Module installed with PIP in virtualenv not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48838606/module-installed-with-pip-in-virtualenv-not-found?noredirect=1&lq=1)

---

```
python -m pip show --files 'BoxSupDataset'

Name: BoxSupDataset
Version: 1.0
Summary: UNKNOWN
Home-page: https://github.com/MaKaNu/PyTorch_Nasa_Dataset
Author: MaKaNu
Author-email: UNKNOWN
License: UNKNOWN
Location: /home/matti/GIT/PytorchLabs/Pytrochlabs-venv-3_7/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by: 
Files:
  BoxSupDataset-1.0-py3.7.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  BoxSupDataset-1.0-py3.7.egg-info/SOURCES.txt
  BoxSupDataset-1.0-py3.7.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  BoxSupDataset-1.0-py3.7.egg-info/top_level.txt
  boxsupdataset/__init__.py
  boxsupdataset/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-37.pyc
  boxsupdataset/__pycache__/nasa_box_sup_dataset.cpython-37.pyc
  boxsupdataset/__pycache__/utils.cpython-37.pyc
  boxsupdataset/nasa_box_sup_dataset.py
  boxsupdataset/transforms/__init__.py
  boxsupdataset/transforms/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-37.pyc
  boxsupdataset/transforms/__pycache__/denoise.cpython-37.pyc
  boxsupdataset/transforms/__pycache__/utils.cpython-37.pyc
  boxsupdataset/transforms/denoise.py
  boxsupdataset/transforms/utils.py
  boxsupdataset/utils.py
```

```
Python 3.7.9 (default, Aug 18 2020, 06:22:45) 
[GCC 7.5.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import BoxSupDataset
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'BoxSupDataset'
>>>
```

Comment: can you try renaming your package

Comment: Do you see any meaningful  files, modules, packages in `python -m pip show --files 'my_package'`? If not, then there might be something wrong with your packaging, and you might want to edit the question to show the directory structure of the project as well as `setup.py` (or `pyproject.toml`).

Comment: @Saandeep Kothari the actual package Name is BoxSupDataset

Comment: @sinroc this is the result of your given command changed to the actual Package name: 
https://pastebin.com/mnWxtyDX

I also included the import with the result below in the pastebin

Comment: The top level package is `boxsupdataset` (all lower case). Can you try `import boxsupdataset` instead of `import BoxSupDataset`?

Comment: okay this worked, but why does this work on windows with PascalCase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be due to a slight confusion between the name of the project (the thing that can be installed) and the name of the *top level package* (the thing that can be imported), with some case sensitivity issues adding to the confusion...

In that particular case the project is indeed named `BoxSupDataset` (that's what you want to install). But the actual *top level package* is `boxsupdataset`, which is the only thing that matters for the imports:

```
import boxsupdataset
```

---

***Aside***:
While on some (*case insensitive*) platforms (such as Windows?) it might be possible to import as `import BoxSupDataset`, the canonical way is `import boxsupdataset` (the exact same name and casing as the package or module). The (somewhat confusing) details can be found in [*PEP 235*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0235/).

Comment: One small question on the Aside: Is there any possibility to check code against pep235, as example with pylint?

Comment: I do not know of anything like that specifically. I would have assumed that _pylint_ itself would notify that the import is wrong. Have you tried it explicitly? I can not try it, I do not have Windows.

Comment: I tested it and my pylint setup is showing as much as it can, so far I know on my WIndows.