# Local module not found in Virtual Environment

Tags: python, command-line, python-venv

Here are the steps I took:

1. Create virtual environment called 'env' with :

   py -m venv env
2. Activate virtual env

.\env\Scripts\activate

3. Install dependencies with a .cfg and .toml with:

   pip install .
4. Try to run python script:

   (env) C:\Users\Steven\Desktop\AIMDyn\klogistics>python src\klogistics_examples\mtf\mtfproject.py
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\Steven\Desktop\AIMDyn\klogistics\src\klogistics_examples\mtf\mtfproject.py", line 7, in 
   from klogistics.project.project import Project
   File "C:\Users\Steven\desktop\AIMDyn\klogistics\env\lib\site-packages\klogistics\project\project.py", line 7, in 
   from klogistics.algorithm.Koopman4COVID19 import Koopman4COVID19 #type: ignore
   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'klogistics.algorithm'
5. Check is klogistics is installed:

   ```
    (env) C:\Users\Steven\Desktop\AIMDyn\klogistics>pip list
   ```

   Package         Version

   ---

   klogistics      0.0.1
   numpy           1.22.3
   pandas          1.4.2
   pip             22.0.4
   python-dateutil 2.8.2
   pytz            2022.1
   scipy           1.8.0
   setuptools      58.1.0
   six             1.16.0

Here is some information that might help:

```
        (env) C:\Users\Steven\Desktop\AIMDyn\klogistics>pip -V
    pip 22.0.4 from C:\Users\Steven\desktop\AIMDyn\klogistics\env\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.10)
    
    (env) C:\Users\Steven\Desktop\AIMDyn\klogistics>python -V
    Python 3.10.4
    
(env) C:\Users\Steven\Desktop\AIMDyn\klogistics>where pip
    C:\Users\Steven\Desktop\AIMDyn\klogistics\env\Scripts\pip.exe
    C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\pip.exe
    
(env) C:\Users\Steven\Desktop\AIMDyn\klogistics>where python
    C:\Users\Steven\Desktop\AIMDyn\klogistics\env\Scripts\python.exe

C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe
```

Comment: I am not entirely sure how to help with this problem, but you might want to check answers from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32004958/python-module-not-found-in-virtualenv

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

I installed the packages in the wrong directory. I installed it in the same level as my env, and packages, when it needed to be one level above.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).